# How to set RingtonePreference value from code?

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I've the following Preference:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <RingtonePreference
    android:showDefault="true"
    android:showSilent="true"
    android:title="@string/feed_alert_ringtone"
    android:ringtoneType="ringtone|notification|alarm|all"
    android:key="alertringtone"
    android:persistent="false">
   </RingtonePreference>     
</PreferenceScreen>
```

When a user changes this preference, I manually save the Uri to a database:

```
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference pref, Object change) {
    String ringtone = change.toString();

    // save it to a db
    ...

    return true;
}
```

My problem is, when the user closes and then gets back to the `PreferenceScreen`, the default Value of the `RingtonePreference` is always `Silence`. Of course, I have to set the value manually.

Tried this one in my `PreferenceActivity`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings); // the XML above

    String database_ringtone = ... // get the string saved above from db
                                   // and according to some parameters passed
                                   // to the intent

    Preference ringtone = findPreference("alertringtone");
    ringtone.setDefaultValue( database_ringtone );

    // also tried:
    ringtone.setDefaultValue( Uri.parse(database_ringtone) );
}
```

Unfortunatly the preference stays at "Silence" (which means empty). I thought, that when the `Preference` is not `persistent` the default value will be used.

I cannot make it `persistent`, because the preference is used for multiple items and the data I get from DB changes according to some extra data passed to the intent.

Nevertheless, I do not want to set the default value, but the current value I get from database. Thought this might be a workaround. So any other way would be good, too.

Double-checked saving and retrieving from DB is working, so that's not the problem.

How can I set the `RingtonePreference` value from code?

---

Edit: Here's a little explanation what I want to do, maybe there's another way.

I've several menu entries (count varies from user to user), for which the user can select a ringtone for. Selecting the ringtone works with the xml above, the ID of the menu entry is passed with an `Intent` to the `PreferenceActivity`. The URI of the ringtone is then stored in the database.

When one of the entries changes, an alarm is played according to the ringtone-selection the user made. So he knows which one changed. No problem so far.

The problem is, when the user wants to change the ringtone for an entry he already defined one for. If the user selected ringtone Foo before, when clicking on the `RingtonePreference`, the ringtone Foo should be preselected already. This is no serious error (more like a glitch), but still very annoying.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to preselect a default `RingtonePreference` from code? Or am I doing it "just wrong"?

---

Edit 2: Okey, I think there isn't a way to do this. Very weird, the android core. Allows us to use a `Preference` and get values from it but not to put values back in. Must have been a real hurry. I'm glad they allowed us to check a `CheckBoxPreference` from code...

Answer (score 6):

I was searching how to set default value for the ringtone, and realized the same thing as you, that when the preference is not set than the value is empty and the silent is selected as default. But I do this

```
// I read my ringtone setting (I read the value from my ringtone_uri key)
// then if it is not set I set the value with the default value from the phone
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Uri configuredUri = Uri.parse(sharedPrefs.getString("ringtone_uri", Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI.toString()));

// then I do this, I save the default ringtone to my settins
if(configuredUri.equals(Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI)){
    sharedPrefs.edit()
            .putString("ringtone_uri", Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI.toString())
            .commit();
}
```

I do not know if this will help you but I hope it will help to someone else. btw I freak out finding this workaround

Comment: Although I can't make much sense of your code (why do you write back the default value if it already is set to the default value?), the code snippet definitely shows how to write to a RingtonePreference from code. Swap out DEFUALT_RINGTONE_URI with the value from the DB, and you solve OP's problem. And I wouldn't call it a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Came across this when trying to solve the exact same problem over 2 years later, didn't find any good answers so I will post my solution.

Unlike a lot of other Preferences, the RingtonePreference does not seem to be affected by calling setDefaultValue().  I tried the same thing and could not get it to work where it worked fine for most other Preferences.

I looked a bit at the API and found a series of callbacks the RingtonePreference uses to store and restore state.  Of particular note is the method [RingtonePreference.onRestoreState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/RingtonePreference.html#onRestoreRingtone%28%29)

So when the Ringtone picker opens, it calls this method to choose which ringtone is selected.
In order to choose a ringtone as selected initially, you have to override this method and return the URI you want to be chosen.

My solution was as follows

```
        //Create a Ringtone Preference
        RingtonePreference ringtonePreference = new RingtonePreference(this){
            @Override
            protected Uri onRestoreRingtone(){
                if(database_ringtone.equals("")){
                    return null;
                }
                else{
                    return Uri.parse(database_ringtone);
                }
            }
        };

        ringtonePreference.setTitle(getString(R.string.pref_title_ringtone));
        ringtonePreference.setPersistent(false);

        //Set the summary to the initial value
        BasePreferenceChangeListener.updatePreference(ringtonePreference, agency.ringtone);

        getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(ringtonePreference);
```

I chose to override the method anonymously and then insert the Preference manually into the PreferenceScreen.

You could also create a subclass of RingtonePreference that overrides the method and then use that subclass in the XML instead of RingtonePreference.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you aren't including a path to the sound file when inserting the ringtone into the database, so it will goto "silent" whenever you try to set from the app.  When you say you must set the value manually, it looks like the sound file is picked up by a media scan of media/ringtones and inserted into the database at that point.  The code below will need to be modified for the way you are doing it, but hope it gives you the right idea.

Try something like:

```
File k = new File(path2, filename);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());

//kill database for this object before inserting
getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);

Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```

Comment: That isn't an answer to what I asked. Selecting ringtone and storing it's URI into the database works (also playing the sound according to the selection made, no problem). I just want the `RingtonePreference` to reflect the choice I made before by preselecting the ringtone when the user opens the preference another time. I'm not adding any custom ringtone with special paths or so.